# chip inside toolbar incorrect vertical alignment

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

#### Problem description

I am trying to put a chip inside a toolbar and am having problems with vertical alignment. I can fix it with overriding some styles of course, but as a real beginner I assume I'm doing something wrong i.e. not using the material-ui components in the right way?

#### Steps to reproduce

If I put a chip as a direct child of an appbar the chips fills the whole height incorrectly:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Agpy.png

`render() {
        return (
        <Toolbar>
            <Chip>
                <Avatar icon={<AccountCircleIcon />} />
                Not signed in
            </Chip>
        </Toolbar>
        )
    }`

If I wrap it in a list item it's height is correct but it still isn't centered in the toolbar:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iULPP.png

`render() {
        return (
        <Toolbar>
            <ListItem disabled={true}>
                <Chip>
                    <Avatar icon={<AccountCircleIcon />} />
                    Not signed in
                </Chip>
            </ListItem>
        </Toolbar>
        )`

What am I doing wrong?
(naturally I want it vertically centered in the toolbar and of the correct height for a chip)

#### Versions

- Material-UI: 0.15.4
- React: 15.3.2
- Browser: Chrome  53.0.2785.116 (Mac OSX)

Comment: This could be solved with a div, flex box, alignItems:center... but have you tried putting your Toolbar items inside of a ToolbarGroup?  I suspect that ToolbarGroup is that center aligned flex box.

Comment: yeah sorry I left the toolbargroup out for brevity it doesn't change anything, and yeah I've just gone the way you suggest and adding my own flexbox'd div to center align them... I just figure everything else magically vertically aligns without any wrappers in the toolbar, so perhaps I was using the chip wrongly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do a mockup (I hate how difficult it is to set up React/Material-Ui problems) and found the same issue.  I think it's expected behavior from how the chip is positioned.

However, it is all fixed with margin: 'auto'

```
render() {
    return (
    <Toolbar>
        <Chip style={{ margin: 'auto' }}>
            <Avatar icon={<AccountCircleIcon />} />
            Not signed in
        </Chip>
    </Toolbar>
    )
}
```